# Synchronous TCP requests using JMeter

Tags: tcp, jmeter, tcpclient

Now I use BinaryTCPClientImpl and CSV data set with hex encoded lines of data. Every JMeter thread create new connection to server and send line of data from CVS file. But I need to have only one thread that will connect to server one time and send all lines from CVS file synchronously (next line after receiving acknowledgment from server). Is it possible to realize it using jMeter?

Comment: did you try by enabling "Re-use connection" checkbox? how many threads are being configured?

Comment: yes. I tried to use "Re-use connection" checkbox, but every thread create new connection. In JMeter documentation is written: 
> If "Re-use connection" is selected, connections are shared between Samplers in the same thread, provided that the exact same host name string and port are used.
How I undersntand it is sharing connections between samplers, but not between threads

Comment: yes. it is shared among Samplers, here I assume there is only Sampler. so, the checkbox is not applicable. by the way, how many threads that you defined?

Comment: For example if I configure 1 threads, only 1 line from file is sent. If I configure 2 threads, every thread create new connection and send one line from file independently from others. But I need one connection and to send data after acknowledgment

Comment: just specify the loop count in JMeter ThreadGroup as 2, so Jmeter creates only one thread and iterate twice with the two values from the csv file. increase the loop couunt as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `Loop Count` in JMeter `Thread Group` as 2, so JMeter creates only one thread and iterates twice with the two values from the CSV file.

Increase the `Loop Count` as per your needs.

You can keep `Loop Count` as `Forever`  (by enabling the checkbox) and in the `CSV Data Config`, set `Recycle on EOF?` to `True`, so that JMeter keep resending the contents from the CSV file.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have set `Loop count = 2`, `Number of Threads (users) = 1`, `Recycle on EOF? = True`. But only the first line from CSV file was sent. How I understand `Recycle on EOF? = True` will start new cycle after end-of-file, not after end-of-line.

Comment: can you please share your CSV Dataset Config screenshot?

Comment: configuration seems fine. pls share the contents of the CSV file? and Thread Group configuration?

Comment: csv file is many lines generated data like this:
`740000003736343234353331303635333139360000000000000000030bbb000000270002706f73696e666f00d17f51d8560e5e404de3bbe3578950409a99999999717840006d010b070bbb0000001200047077725f65787400e3a59bc420f02b400bbb00000011000361766c5f696e707574730000000008`

Comment: can you please share it as a screenshot of the csv file? I need to see how the content is present inside? open it with Notepad++ or excel whichever tool you have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129425/discussion-between-naveen-and-yaahor).

Comment: click on the link share in above comment to discuss the issue

Comment: can you share the jmx file as an example of how to use TCP sampler with CSV data set